# Fixed URL after returning view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I use ASP CORE 2.0 and this is my controller class:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("Add")]
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

my Navbar has the following links:

```
   <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
   <a asp-controller="Foo" asp-action="Create">Create</a>
```

Everything works good, but if I click on 'Create' and get the 'CreateView' back my URL is:

```
localhost:port/Add
```

It doesn't matter which other link I click on my Navbar, it's always

```
localhost:port/Add
```

so I have to modify the URL by my own (removing the '/Add')...

How can I solve this?

Comment: I want different naming convention. On Backend-side I want the term 'create' but for the client the term 'add'...

Comment: then don't use httpget unless you are using this with a webapi instead try `[ActionName("Add")]`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("Add")] // Attribute Routing
    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Attribute Routing** :attribute routing uses attributes to define routes. Attribute routing gives you more control over the URIs in your web API.

So If you request your Create Action then the Url will be localhost:port/Add instead of localhost:port/Create. If you want Create in the url then :

```
 public class FooController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet] // Remove "Add"
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```